# "An year ago" vs "an year back"

Tags: phrase-usage

> I was like you an year ago

> I was like you an year back

Are both these sentences correct and natural?

Comment: Spelling:  "a year" not "an year".

Comment: For the question.  Please don't do the "is this natural"? question.  Why do you have a doubt? Why do think there might be a problem?  Have you found examples of these online? Have you found anything similar?

Comment: @JamesK Until now I used to think that year is pronounced with an "e" sound. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesK I keep using them both interchangeably so I was making sure I'm doing it right. I asked if it's natural bcoz it might still be awkward after being grammatically correct. I should've put in more effort in looking for examples online. Won't disappoint you next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same in meaning, You can use both alternatively.

A year back=A year ago

Comment: Except that it's '**a** year'.